# Can I use form linking in a CommCare app that uses advanced modules?

Tags: commcare

Is form linking functionality as end of form navigation an option for application using advanced modules? Are there any caveats to using form linking in advanced modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to this is yes, it does. Slightly longer answer is that the way form linking interacts with Advanced Modules is complex, brittle, and not recommended.

As an alternative option, you can set your form navigation to "Module: Your Module". Then at the end of the form include an image of the icon of the form they should select next. This way the user sees which icon they're supposed to choose next and are sent directly to the list of forms they can choose from.